# How to merge 2 dataframes with 4 columns each into a matrix with each cell returning the intersect

Tags: r, matrix, intersect

I have 2 datasets and I want to compare each columns between the 2 datasets and get their intersects. how do i go about this? I have an example below to better explain what i wish to be returned. I am working with Rstudio.

dt1 =

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dog | rabbit | bird | pig | dog | bird |
| cat | turtle | cat | rabbit | rabbit | dog |
| pig | bird | dog | turtle | turtle | pig |

dt2=

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rabbit | dog | lion | turtle | fish | bird |
| giraffe | bird | cat | dog | worm | dog |
| pig | cat | pig | rabbit | dog | pig |

expected return matrix=

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| intersect(dt1col1,dt2col1) | intersect(dt1col1,dt2col2) | intersect(dt1col1,dt2col3) | intersect(dt1col1,dt2col4) | intersect(dt1col1,dt2col5) | intersect(dt1col1,dt2col6) |
| intersect(dt1col2,dt2col1) | intersect(dt1col2,dt2col2) | intersect(dt1col2,dt2col3) | intersect(dt1col2,dt2col4) | intersect(dt1col2,dt2col5) | intersect(dt1col2,dt2col6) |
| intersect(dt1col3,dt2col1) | intersect(dt1col3,dt2col2) | intersect(dt1col3,dt2col3) | intersect(dt1col3,dt2col4) | intersect(dt1col3,dt2col5) | intersect(dt1col3,dt2col6) |
| intersect(dt1col4,dt2col1) | intersect(dt1col4,dt2col2) | intersect(dt1col4,dt2col3) | intersect(dt1col4,dt2col4) | intersect(dt1col4,dt2col5) | intersect(dt1col4,dt2col6) |
| intersect(dt1col5,dt2col1) | intersect(dt1col5,dt2col2) | intersect(dt1col5,dt2col3) | intersect(dt1col5,dt2col4) | intersect(dt1col5,dt2col5) | intersect(dt1col5,dt2col6) |
| intersect(dt1col6,dt2col1) | intersect(dt1col6,dt2col2) | intersect(dt1col6,dt2col3) | intersect(dt1col6,dt2col4) | intersect(dt1col6,dt2col5) | intersect(dt1col6,dt2col6) |

Answer (score 1):

Try `outer`

```
> outer(dt1, dt2, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) toString(intersect(x, y))))
     col1          col2             col3       col4                  col5 
col1 "pig"         "dog, cat"       "cat, pig" "dog"                 "dog"
col2 "rabbit"      "bird"           ""         "rabbit, turtle"      ""
col3 ""            "bird, cat, dog" "cat"      "dog"                 "dog"
col4 "pig, rabbit" ""               "pig"      "rabbit, turtle"      ""
col5 "rabbit"      "dog"            ""         "dog, rabbit, turtle" "dog"
col6 "pig"         "bird, dog"      "pig"      "dog"                 "dog"
     col6
col1 "dog, pig"
col2 "bird"
col3 "bird, dog"
col4 "pig"
col5 "dog"
col6 "bird, dog, pig"
```

Comment: If I wanted it to show the number of intersected items, instead of a list of items. how can I edit the code which you did?

Comment: @Amirul Hakim use `length` instead of `toString`